# Disable window highlight in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac

I clicked on something and now all my windows have a black boundary around them whenever I focus on it. This happens on menu bar items as well when in focus. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 4):

You've turned on a feature called "Voice Over" which can be toggled by hitting <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Alternatively go to System Preferences -> Universal Access and turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: open the System Preferences, select Universal Access, and then ensure "VoiceOver" is switched off. Let me know if this solves the problem.